# Do personal cheques expire? [Canada]

Tags: canada, check, expiration

In Canada, cheques issued by the Government of Canada do not expire.  do personal cheques ever expire?  If so, what is the limit before they need to be re-issued?

Comment: In India, recently the limit has been reduced to just three months.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Expire** is not really the right term; but effectively yes.

In general a cheque older than six months will be considered *stale-dated* and will not be honoured.  Reference the [Canadian Payments Association FAQ](https://www.cdnpay.ca/imis15/eng/FAQs/Cheque_Clearing/eng/faq/Cheque_Clearing.aspx#bm07)