# Adding a 180 day expiration to checks

Tags: united-states, checking-account, check

I've had several checks that I've written in the past go un-deposited for over a year.  Is it worth it to have "Void after 180 days" printed on my checks?  I know that banks are not obligated to honor a check after 6 months but my question is has anyone had experience where this has happened.  i.e  a check with this on it was refused because it had expired.

Comment: There is a similar question at
http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/do-personal-checks-expire-us

Comment: @Dheer  Thanks I did see that question and answer.  My question is actually because of that answer, and is more about what has been peoples individual experiences given the ambiguity of it.

Comment: You can always issue a stop check order with your bank on an old check you'd rather not be cashed (or on any check for that matter). Most banks will charge varying fees for this, and often the stop orders have expiration dates too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While you can print that on the check, it isn't considered legally binding.

If you are concerned about a check not being deposited in a timely manner, consider purchasing a cashier's check instead. This doesn't solve the problem per se, but it transfers responsibility of tracking that check from you to the bank.

Comment: Chamgers, that's a good idea for if I have a concern prior to writing a check, I guess a money order would work also... on the other hand if it NEVER does get cashed, with a personal check I get to keep the money.

Answer (score 3):

Your bank has discretion to honor checks after 6 months, so you should talk to your bank about their specific policy.

In general, banks won't accept "large" stale checks. The meaning of "large" varies -- $25,000 in NYC, as little as $2k in other places. Banks that service high-volume check issuers (like rebate companies) reject checks at 180 days.

For business purposes, I think some banks will create accounts for specific mailings or other purposes as well. (i.e. 2011 refund account) The accounts close after a year.