# Check expiry date

Tags: united-states, banking, check

I have received a banker's check which HSBC New York sent after closing my account. There is no mention of expiry date. Can somebody inform me how many months are USA checks valid?

Comment: generally, six months in the US. See related question: http://money.stackexchange.com/questions/1551/do-personal-checks-expire-us

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.law.cornell.edu/ucc/4/4-404

Article §4-404 of the UCC:

"A bank is under no obligation to a customer having a checking account to pay a check, other than a certified check, which is presented more than six months after its date, but it may charge its customer's account for a payment made thereafter in good faith."

While not 100% applicable, it's probably a good rule of thumb.

Comment: Thanks! Is a printed check from the bank a certified check? How to know it is one?